# The domain of the Friedrichs extension and the quadratic form

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

It might be easier to explain my question with an example, so consider $T = -\Delta + |x|^2$ the quantum harmonic oscillator. I'd like to understand two questions: one is about the domain of the Friedrichs extension and the other is about the quadratic form characterisation. Basically I want to understand the [Wikipedia explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrichs_extension) a bit better.

**My first question is about the requirement of density.** Does the Friedrichs extension (to the domain $H_1$, the completion of $D(T)$ with respect to the sesquilinear form $Q$) actually work for any nonnegative operator, and that the density of the domain, which in the case of the quantum harmonic oscillator we can take as $D(T) = $ finite linear combinations of Hermite polynomials $(H_n)$, the eigenfunctions of (the extension of) $T$, is what guarantees the extension is to all of $H_1 = L^2$? I think the argument is we want to show if we have a $Q$-Cauchy sequence, it is $L^2$-Cauchy, and so the closure of $D(T)$ with respect to $Q$ contains at least the closure of $D(T)$ with respect to $L^2$, which is all of $L^2$ by density. Is this right?

**My second question is related to the quadratic form definition.** Wikipedia says (swapping $\xi, \eta$ for $f, g$) that the extension $T$ satisfies, for $f, g \in H_1 = L^2$, the formula
$$ Q(f, g) = (Tf, g)_{L^2}. $$
So I understand the right hand side is finite since our extension maps $f \in L^2$ to $Tf \in L^2$ and so we can apply Cauchy-Schwarz, but why is the left hand side finite? For the harmonic oscillator, isn't the quadratic form $Q$ defined by
$$ Q(f, g) = (|2\pi \xi|^2\hat{f},\hat{g}) + (|x|^2f, g) + (f, g) = \int |2\pi\xi|^2\hat{f}(\xi)\overline{\hat{g}(\xi)}d\xi + \int (|x|^2 + 1)f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx? $$

Is the theorem actually saying the extension has the additional property $Q(f, g) = (Tf, g)_{L^2} < \infty$ for all $f, g \in L^2$? I really don't understand how we can even write down $Q$ outside of the domain $D(T)$, and this seems very false, e.g. isn't it false by taking $f = g$ and satisfying $\int |x|^2|f(x)|^2dx = \infty$?

EDIT: To simplify the problem, I don't even understand how the Friedrichs extension of (say) the operator $T = -\Delta$ or $T = |x|^2$ works. These are nonnegative, symmetric, and densely defined again on the linear span of the Hermite polynomials $(H_n)$. How can we possibly ensure $Tf \in L^2$ when we can choose, e.g. $f(x) = (1 + |x|^2)^{-(n+1)/4} \in L^2$?

Comment: In the first question, one needs closable operator to make sure $H_1$ is embedded in $L^2.$ $H_1 \subsetneq L^2$ although $H_1$ and $L^2$ are likely to be isomorphic as abstract Hilbert spaces.

Comment: @dsh I see, so does that mean all of my problems are basically due to the fact I've claimed $H_1 \subset L^2$? So I should not be thinking of the extension as acting on $L^2$ but acting on (provided we have a dense domain) a new Hilbert space which is (probably) isomorphic to $L^2$?

Comment: When $D(T)$ is considered, one needs the following fact: if $f_n$ is $Q$-Cauchy and $f_n\to 0$ in $L^2$-norm then $f_n\to 0$ in $Q$-norm. It guarantees that no 2 elements of $H_1$ correspond to the same element of $L^2.$ $H_1 \subset L^2$ is correct claim with clarification that $H_1 \neq L^2$  and $H_1$ consitutes dense subset of $L^2$ for most of the forms $Q.$ Isomorphism between $H_1$ and $L^2$ is not helpful in this context at all, I would suggest reviewing facts ignoring isomorphism.